# Why idField is undefined in ng-multiselect-dropdown in angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular app in which i have `ng-multiselect-dropdown`. To provide list to `dropdown` i am getting `services` from an `api` inside of `ngOnInit` like this

```
selectedOfferedServices: IDropdownSettings = {};

ngOnInit(){
   this.getServices();
   this.selectedOfferedServices = {
     singleSelection: false,
     idField: 'id',
     textField: 'deliveryTypeName',
     selectAllText: 'Select All',
     unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
     itemsShowLimit: 2,
     allowSearchFilter: false
   };
}
```

And inside my `template` i have a condition of `*ngIf` and upon getting the true inside of `*ngIf` expression this `ng-multiselect-dropdown` is shown. When user selects any option from normal `select` dropdwon in my template so this expression becomes true and then this `ng-multi-select-dropdown` is shown.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="transporterOtherDetails === 'yes'">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Offered Services</label>
          <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select services'" [data]="deliverytypes"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedServices" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          [settings]="dropdownSettings">
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem here is that when i select option from normal `dropdown` in my template so this `ng-multi-select-dropdown` shows but in console error is coming like this

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'idField' of undefined at ng-multiselect-dropdown.js:189
```

can any one let me know that what's the issue with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I fixed this issue to just move my `settings` param before `data` param. And this works for me.